# Log4Net log to application insights and to a file

Tags: log4net, azure-application-insights

I'm using Log4Net and Application Insights. I'm successfully logging to app insights using the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender package but this stops all logging to my log file on the server. Ideally, I'd like to have Log4Net send data to app insights but also maintain my RollingFileAppender as well. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can just add both appenders to your logging configuration. Both appenders will log.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that adding the Log4NetAppender package updated the web.config with the log4net settings so my external log4net config file that included the RollingFileAppender was ignored. It's working fine now.